# How to uplode a song in my laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

I want to make a sound on my welcome page!! i don't know where i put the mp3 file in my project neither how to call it. 
 i have created a folder under public named sounds where i put my .mp3 file and did this in blade page

```
<embed height="60" type="audio/midi" width="144" src="sounds/kism.mp3" volume="60" loop="false" autostart="true" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use html5 to embed an audio source like this:

```
<audio controls preload="auto" autoplay="true">
    <source src="/sounds/kism.mp3" />
    This text displays if the audio tag isn't supported.
</audio>
```

Comment: u helped ^_^ thaanks